# Remove border from a notebook

Tags: gtk, gtkmm, gtk3

I have a GtkNotebook and inside a GtkScrollView with a GtkImage. The Notebook is at the bottom-right side of the window (above is the toolbar, to the left is an options pane), and I would like to remove the border to the bottom/right from the Notebook (i.e. from each page), marked red in the screenshot below.

The following didn't have any effect (for the right side only), using the Ambiance theme.

```
notebook->get_style_context()->set_junction_sides(JUNCTION_RIGHT);
notebook->get_style_context()->get_border().set_right(0);
notebook->set_show_border(false);
```

[image: my situation]

Answer (score 0):

I haven not managed to do this myself, but this might help:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123408